# How do i attach a value for if a checkbox is checked in HTML?

Tags: html, checkbox

I want to make an assignment where people look up an e-mail on a list of websites. If there I no e-mail to be found, I want them to check a box. If they check the box I want it to return a value like: "no e-mail found". Is there an easy way to do this? I'm holding a survey in Amazon Mturk.

Below you can find my current code. I have barely any knowledge of HTML.

[image]

Comment: Don't poste images of code. Make a workable snippet here.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the attached image I searched for 'crowd-checkbox' and found the documentation for that element. You can look at it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-crowd-checkbox.html). If you go down to the 'Output' section you can see two examples of how you can set the value property of the checkbox element and how it looks when outputted as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you  can use `on change` event of checkbox input:
In this code the `span` content changes as checkbox value changes.

```js
$('#email_chk').change(function(){
  var res = this.checked? "Is checked": "Not checked";
  $('.result').text(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Email : <input type="checkbox" id="email_chk" />
<br />
Result : <span class="result">Not checked</span>
```